# No new server Runtime Environment found"

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I could not able to install Apache tomcat 7.0 in my eclipse Kepler.I have installed Apache Tomcat 7.0, Java EE perspective and done all the path sets.But when I try to add a server using Windows Preference Tab,then i do not find Apache tomcat,Even I tried to go to the tomcat installation directory using search button,it is showing "no new server Runtime Environment found"

Comment: You need to add the server to eclipse. Did you do it? Check this [link](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.stardust.docs.wst%2Fhtml%2Fwst-integration%2Fconfiguration.html)